# Android device cannot parse package

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing, apk

I know this question has been asked before but previous answers have not helped me solve my problem. From Eclipse, I've tried exporting the apk or simply copying the apk from the bin file, and sent it to myself via email. However, when I try to install it by opening the attachment, there is a "parse error." I'm not quite sure what the problem is. This has worked before so my device is probably up to date. The other reason would be that the apk would be corrupted, but I don't see how that's possible if I got it directly from Eclipse.

Comment: Can you install the apk directly from eclipse with the run button or via adb?  Will it install to an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions:

1. Uninstall any other apps with the same package name
2. Check: Unknown Sources
3. Download the apk and open it with something other than your email client/browser such as: [Easy Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.installer&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating a unsigned APK? Sometimes Eclipse acts in strange ways and the apk in the bin folder doesn't work.

Try using right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Export Unsigned Application Package

Then select your destination folder.

If the problem persists, as Randy pointed out, uninstall any previous version of that app in your device.

Hope it helped.

Comment: You can't install an unsigned apk - you'd have to sign it from the command line first.